# How do I know if my Button insersects with another button?

Tags: c#

I have a form with a button (btPlayer) then I wanna know if my button intersects with another button.

But I don't know the names of the buttons, I know only the name of "btPlayer".

How do I do something like this? :

```
 if(btPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(>>>>>ANYBUTTON()<<) {

      // ... do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **WinForms** and all the Buttons are contained **directly by the Form**:

```
    private void btPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Button btn in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            if (!btn.Equals(btPlayer))
            {
                if (btPlayer.Bounds.IntersectsWith(btn.Bounds))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("btPlayer intersects with " + btn.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really thought about this. But I didn't know if this way is efficient. But it solves my problem! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the collection of buttons on your form. Note that this isn't necessarily as easy as it sounds, as:

```
Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

Won't grab *nested* buttons (such as those in a panel or group box). Once you have your collection, its as simple as:

```
//Not recursive, make sure we don't include ourself
IEnumerable<Button> allButtons = Controls.OfType<Button>()
                                 .Except(new List<Button>() { btPlayer })();
if (allButtons.Any(b => b.Bounds.IntersectsWith(btPlayer))
{
   //An intersection has occurred!
}
```